# Difference between "Song", "Sang", and "Gesang"

Tags: meaning, difference

"Der Sang", "der Gesang", and "der Song" all mean "a song". What are the differences, if any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Song *vs.* Lied

One word is missing from the list, namely *Lied*. A *Lied* is a piece of music which is supposed to be sung, a song. For certain types of songs the word *Song* taken from English can be used instead of *Lied*, however while you might speak of a *Beatles-Song* you would not speak of a *Schumann-Song*.

### Gesang

The word *Gesang* denotes singing.

> Ich lauschte ihrem Gesang.

means that I listened to someone singing, it does not imply that the song she sang was hers.

### Sang

*Sang* is a variant of *Gesang* which is mostly obsolete, but preserved in certain expressions (*mit Sang und Klang*, *sang- und klanglos*). It also occurs in the second stanza of the [Deutschlandlied](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschlandlied) (note *-lied*):

> Deutsche Frauen, deutsche Treue, 
> Deutscher Wein und deutscher Sang
> Sollen in der Welt behalten
> Ihren alten schönen Klang,
> Uns zu edler Tat begeistern
> Unser ganzes Leben lang.

Now, that is a form of patriotism that I can live with, even though its sexual politics are a bit outdated.

Comment: Du würdest nicht von einem Schumann-Song sprechen - was andere würden weißt Du nicht. Ich kenne einen populären Autor der auch nicht vor einem Song den Orpheus sang zurückschreckte.